# Erro ao inserir no banco de dados Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Como faço para inserir o objeto ProdutoIngrediente no banco de dados que é composto por um objeto Ingrediente que já existe no banco de dados, sem duplicar o objeto Ingrediente na base de dados. Se eu retirar o cascade e colocar no Ingrediente o ID (primary key auto increment) do objeto, dá erro. O correto não seria o Hibernate não salvar o objeto? Será que no momento da inserção ele menospreza o ID por ser auto increment?

Erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : entity.ProdutoIngrediente.ingrediente -> entity.Ingrediente
```

Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "produto_ingrediente")
public class ProdutoIngrediente implements java.io.Serializable {
           ......
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_ingrediente", nullable = false)
    public Ingrediente getIngrediente() {
        return this.ingrediente;
    }

    public void setIngrediente(Ingrediente ingrediente) {
        this.ingrediente = ingrediente;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "produto", catalog = "grupotenkite2")
public class Produto implements java.io.Serializable {
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_produto", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdProduto() {
        return this.idProduto;
    }
}
```

[image: Relação entre o produto e ingrediente]

Comment: Erro de projeto. Se existe um atributo que não pode ser duplicado ele deveria ser a chave e não criar um auto-incremento.

Comment: Poste os ids das suas entidades, a modelagem dos relacionamentos, bem como seu esquema de dados. Pelo que entendi a tabela `produto_ingrediente` é uma tabela de relacionamento many-to-many (provavelmente com atributos extras, o que justifica a decisão de ter uma entidade separada).

Comment: Se for esse o caso, modele a entidade com uma chave composta e relacionamentos se valendo de `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`s (e reflita isso no banco criando uma PK Composta, o que evita ingredientes duplicados para o mesmo produto). Você poderá persistir a entidade sem problemas. [Exemplo - Em Inglês](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns). Pense no `addEmployee(Employee employee, boolean teamLead)` como, por exemplo `adicionarIngrediente(Ingrediente ingrediente, BigDecimal quantidade)`;

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly dê uma olhada no diagrama de entidade e relacionamento que eu coloquei, por favor. O que você me recomenda. a intenção é deixar que um produto tenha mais um ingrediente.. No meu programa, primeiro insiro todos os ingredientes do sistema e depois adiciono o produto e faço a conexão através da tabela 'produto_ingrediente'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como eu modelaria o problema.

## Banco de Dados

1. Removeria a PK `id_produtoIngrediente` completamente. Ela permite que o mesmo ingrediente seja repetido para um produto, o que não reflete o seu negócio (cada ingrediente será associado uma única vez ao produto):

   ```sql
   alter table produto_ingrediente drop column id_produtoIngrediente;
   ```
2. No lugar da PK artificial usaria um PK composta natural:

   ```sql
   alter table produto_ingrediente add primary key(id_produto, id_ingrediente);
   ```

   Esse novo modelo não permite que o mesmo ingrediente seja associado múltiplas vezes a um produto ou vice-versa.

## JPA

1. Naturalmente, sua entidade `ProdutoIngrediente` deve refletir a chave composta:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="produto_ingrediente")
   @IdClass(ProdutoIngredienteId.class)
   public class ProdutoIngrediente implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @Column(name="id_produto", nullable = false)
      private Integer idProduto;
      @Id
      @Column(name="id_ingrediente", nullable = false)
      private Integer idIngrediente;
      @ManyToOne
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_produto")
      private Produto produto;
      @ManyToOne
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_ingrediente")
      private Ingrediente ingrediente;

      // Demais campos...
      // Getters & Setters
      // equals e hashCode como abaixo
   }
   ```
2. Reparou na anotação `@IdClass` para mapear uma chave composta? Na verdade você pode escolher entre [essa sintaxe para chaves compostas](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Composite_Primary_Key_) ou uma sintaxe ligeiramente diferente usando [chaves embutidas](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Embedded_Primary_Key_). Pessoalmente acho a primeira variação mais limpa. Sendo assim, segue uma implementação para `ProdutoIngredienteId`:

   ```
   public class ProdutoIngredienteId {
       private Integer idProduto;
       private Integer idIngrediente;

       // getters & setters

       // Métodos de exemplo gerados com o IDE
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if (this == o) return true;
           if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
           ProdutoIngredienteId that = (ProdutoIngredienteId) o;
           if (!idIngrediente.equals(that.idIngrediente)) return false;
           if (!idProduto.equals(that.idProduto)) return false;

           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           int result = idProduto.hashCode();
           result = 31 * result + idIngrediente.hashCode();
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Do lado do produto você possui uma coleção de associações. Como as associações são únicas e a ordem dos ingredientes não parece ser importante, acredito que um `Set` seja mais apropriado que uma `List`:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "produto", catalog = "grupotenkite2")
   public class Produto implements java.io.Serializable {    
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
       @Column(name = "id_produto", unique = true, nullable = false)
       private Integer idProduto;
       @OneToMany(mappedBy="produto")
       private Set<ProdutoIngrediente> ingredientes;

       // getters & setters
   ```
4. Finalmente, como é responsabilidade da sua aplicação manter as duas pontas de uma relação bidirecional, o código para associar um ingrediente a um produto é um tanto quanto tedioso:

   ```
       Produto pizza = em.find(Produto.class, idPizza);
       Ingrediente farinha = em.find(Ingrediente.class, idFarinha);

       // Cria a associacao (tabela many to many)
       ProdutoIngrediente associacao = new ProdutoIngrediente();
       associacao.setProduto(pizza);
       associacao.setIngrediente(farinha);
       associacao.setIdProduto(pizza.getId());
       associacao.setIdIngrediente(farinha.getId());

       // demais parâmetros da associação

       // adiciona a associacao do lado do produto
       pizza.getIngredientes().add(associacao);
       // adiciona a associacao do lado do ingrediente (se existir)
       farinha.getProdutos().add(associacao);
   ```

   Dessa maneira, como você irá adicionar ingredientes persistidos ao produto, você pode esconder a complexidade da associação em um método do `Produto`;

   ```
   public boolean adicionarIngrediente(Ingrediente ingrediente, boolean opcional, 
           boolean padrao, BigDecimal valor) { // ...
   ```

   A vantagem de fazer isso é que seu código cliente não terá que lidar com associações diretamente, podendo adicionar novos ingredientes ao produto de maneira natural:

   ```
   Produto pizza = em.find(Produto.class, idPizza);
   Ingrediente farinha = em.find(Ingrediente.class, idFarinha);
   pizza.adicionarIngrediente(farinha, false, true, new BigDecimal("0.60"));
   ```

   Se a quantidade de parâmetros da associação começar a crescer demais repense seu modelo e crie um objeto auxiliar.

**OBS1:** preferi usar as anotações nos campos, mas você pode adaptar esse código para anotar propriedades conforme seu código atual.

**OBS2:** Desculpe a resposta gigante, mas prefiro correr o risco de ser pedante ao risco de assumir conhecimento prévio e pular alguma informação importante para a solução do problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esforço.. ficou claro o problema e a solução, vou tentar adaptá-la ao meu código :)

Comment: Não há de que. Boa sorte! :)